# How to run a exe Asynchronously with two arguments in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shell, rubygems

exe should run when i am open the page. Asynchronous process need to run.

Is there any way for run exe Asynchronously with two arguments in ruby?

i have tried ruby commands - system() , exec() but its waiting the process complete. i need to start exe with parameter no need to wait for  the process complete

is any rubygems going to support for my issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Process.spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn) and [`Process.wait2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-wait2):

```
pid = Process.spawn 'your.exe', '--option'

# Later...
pid, status = Process.wait2 pid
```

Your program will be executed as a child process of the interpreter. Besides that, it will behave as if it had been invoked from the command line.

You can also use [`Open3.popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3):

```
require 'open3'
*streams, thread = Open3.popen3 'your.exe', '--option'

# Later...
streams.each &:close
status = thread.value
```

The main difference here is that you get access to three [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) objects. The standard input, output and error streams of the process are redirected to them, in that order.

This is great if you intend to consume the output of the program, or communicate with it through its standard input stream. Text that would normally be printed on a terminal will instead be made available to your script.

You also get a thread which will wait for the program to finish executing, which is convenient and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` switches control to a new process and never returns. `system` creates a subprocess and waits for it to finish.

What you probably want to do is `fork` and then `exec` to create a new process without waiting for it to return. You can also use the `win32ole` library which might [give you more control](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.ca/2007/05/launching-apps-and-printing-docs-with.html).